# trying to put my <h1>title</h1> above my image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im trying to do something, but I dont know if its possible.

I have a html structure for desktop and tablet devices and its working fine, but now for mobile, I want to change a little bit the structure of my news.

In mobile version I want to put my `<h1>Title of the news</h1>` above the image, but its appearing below the image, because in my html I have the title image first, but I dont want to change my html structure,  its not possible to put my title above my image with only CSS?

Im trying some tests but nothing is working!

I put my example in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zkpj7/

For a better understanding, I have this images to show what I Want:

[image]

Comment: Using `position: absolute;`, you can put the element anywhere you want, but it would bit somewhat hacky and unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing CSS like this:

```
#news
{
    height:140px; 
    margin-bottom:5px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding-bottom:43px;    
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 45px; /*CHANGE VALUE ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS*/
}

#news h2 {
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; /*ABSOLUTE POSITIONING*/
    margin: 0px;
}

#news span 
{
    color:#7a7a7a;
    position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 0px; /*ABSOLUTE POSITIONING*/
}
```

I can't think of a good solution that would not use absolute positioning...

I really would suggest changing the markup though :p

http://jsfiddle.net/Zkpj7/9/

Comment: Thank you, your code its working but with some problems! Because my paragraph and date are appear behind the title and the image!

Comment: Yes, thank you! It worked, I really need to understand better the position relative and absolute! But do you think this is correct to do?

Comment: It is absolutely correct to use absolute positioning, although you should be careful when to use it. If you plan your whole website with absolute positioning you will run into trouble because of different screen and font sizes on your user's client. However in a certain context - a containing element - it is usually fine to use absolute positioning. The container must be positioned relative, so the absolute positions like top, left etc. will correspond to the boundaries of the container.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS answers will all be less than ideal since CSS is for changing style not structure. I would recommend using jquery. Call this on the id's for the title and picture to reorder them.

```
$("#title").insertBefore("#pic");
```

If you want, add something like this to fire when the screen size gets too small (set whatever threshold you want).

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 400){
     $("#title").insertBefore("#pic");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, seems a good solution but Im testing this if($(window).width() <180){alert('hello')} and in a smartphone sony ericsson live walkman, the message appears, but in samsung galaxy express dont appears the message. And the resolution is 480px! I alredy try with if($(window).width() <960){ alert('hello')} but in samsung still dont appears!

Comment: Maybe  the better way is to create in my html a new div and show that new div in mobile versions, and in mobile versions  hide the div that is for desktop and tablet, no?

Comment: Since article is a container with relative positioning, absolute positioning should be ok. Changing the markup would be a lot better...to use JQuery for such a thing seems to be just as much of a bad practice as keeping this kind of markup...however if you end up doing it this way make sure you add $(document).ready(...); as well :p

Comment: $(window).width gives you the viewport width of smartphones, which usually is a lot bigger than the actual device width. Pixels are an angular measurement, but don't want to confuse you, just add the following to the head of your page: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />